# Swift switches and case function handling

Tags: swift

I'm working on an open source project while learning swift at the same time, the github repository is available at https://github.com/istx25/schedules. I'm trying to add an identifier to the case that will run a function everytime the button is pressed in a UIActionSheet. The code for the action sheet is as follows:

```
@IBAction func rightButton(sender : AnyObject) {
    var sheet: UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet()
    let title: String = "Please choose a block rotation"
    sheet.title  = title
    sheet.delegate = self
    sheet.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
    sheet.addButtonWithTitle("Day Four")
    sheet.addButtonWithTitle("Day Three")
    sheet.addButtonWithTitle("Day Two")
    sheet.addButtonWithTitle("Day One")
    sheet.cancelButtonIndex = 0
    sheet.showInView(self.view)
}
```

and I've started the switch to defer which button is which as:

```
func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
        switch buttonIndex {
        case 0:
            print("Go Back")
        case 1:
            print("Day Four")
            // Day Four Function
        case 2:
            print("Day Three")
            // Day Three Function
        case 3:
            print("Day Two")
            // Day Two Function
        case 4:
            print("Day One")
            // Day One Function
        default:
            print("Something's broken")
        }
    }
```

I'm wanting each case to be pushed to it's own `func` method and I'm not sure exactly how I would approach this, so please if anybody could help that would be great. If this question is hard to understand please tell me; so I can get better at asking for help on Stackoverflow! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean in place of those `print ...` calls, you want to use a function instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a separate func, and pass in buttonIndex. There you could either do if's or the same switch.

```
func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
            switch buttonIndex {
            case 0:
                print("Go Back")
                theFuction(buttonIndex)
            case 1:
                print("Day Four")
                // Day Four Function
                theFuction(buttonIndex)
            case 2:
                print("Day Three")
                // Day Three Function
                theFuction(buttonIndex)
            case 3:
                print("Day Two")
                // Day Two Function
                theFuction(buttonIndex)
            case 4:
                print("Day One")
                // Day One Function
                theFuction(buttonIndex)
            default:
                print("Something's broken")
            }
        }

    func theFuction (btnIndex: Int) {
        if btnIndex == 0 {

        } else if btnIndex == 1 {

        } else if btnIndex == 2 {

        } else if btnIndex == 3 {

        } else if btnIndex == 4 {

        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the advantage of having another method with if/elses which call the methods that you want, over just doing that in the cases of the switch? This just seems duplicative/redundant to me.

Comment: Java and C++ UI code shouldn't fit this pattern. I realize object orientation is something of a retrofit onto iOS/Mac OS, but it's hard to believe this is considered optimal design. The beginning of _iOS Progamming_ from Big Nerd Ranch shows making connections in the XCode UI designer, then implementing one response per UI control. That sounds more reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

If you're targeting iOS 8 then you shouldn't be using UIActionSheets as they are deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet and add actions to it with the addAction() method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Swift (yet), but the usual setup is *not* with switch/case. Instead each button is associated with an action. That might be a callback. Here, UIControl.sendAction and related code looks like the place to start.

Comment: You made a good guess but it is not correct. You can easily find out by checking the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIActionSheetDelegate/actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:

Comment: @AnthonyKong Your link is to a deprecated API.

Comment: In the context of OP's question, he is using `UIActionSheet`

Comment: @AnthonyKong Frankly, misusing. Seriously: UI code shouldn’t be full of switch statements on which component signaled. I don't even have to know the One Best Way to know that.

Comment: Totally agree. But you can see the design of the API of UIActionSheet requires the user to do just that. Maybe it is why it get deprecated in iOS8.

Comment: Undoubtedly. I saw better frameworks than that on Mac System 6.